# Why can't I serialize an object with a struct in it?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an "options" object that I'm trying to save to `Settings`

```
public class MainWindow
{
    public MyOptions MyOptions => (MyOptions)DataContext;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = Settings.Default.MyOptions ?? new MyOptions();
    }

    private void OnOptionsChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default.MyOptions = MyOptions;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    // etc.
}
```

`MyOptions` contains *(among other things)* a struct-value

```
public class MyOptions
{
    private MyStruct _myStruct;

    public MyOptions()
    {
        _myStruct = someDefaultValue;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

`MyStruct` contains only a single int:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    private readonly int _someValue;
    public MyStruct(int someValue)
    {
        _someValue = someValue;
    }

    // etc.
}
```

When I make the call to `Settings.Default.MyOptions = MyOptions;`, all the values are set correctly, including `myStruct`.

However, when I restart the program and load the options with `DataContext = Settings.Default.MyOptions`, all the values are correctly loaded **except for _myStruct, which defaults to 0**!

According to everything I've read, this code should work.  I've tried adding the `[Serializable]` attribute to both the class/struct, as well as implementing `ISerializable` (which I shouldn't have to do), but neither helped.  What am I missing?

Comment: My first guess would be that it's not `struct` that's the problem, it's `readonly`. Deserialisation works by creating an instance of an object and then setting its fields. I can imagine why that wouldn't work with `readonly` fields. But this is completely untested guesswork.

Comment: Have you tried make someValue public, and make constructor parameterless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this struct, in my test case it serialized right way:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So `private` values can be serialized in classes but not structs?  Is this documented anywhere?  EDIT: I believe my question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445915/deep-xml-serialize-a-struct-options).  It seems there's no good way to do deep-serialization of objects using `Settings`.  Ugh, what a ridiculous design oversight.

Answer (score 2):

Settings are serialized as XML, which has a [limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13401220/335858) of excluding `readonly` members.

Removing `readonly` qualifier should fix this problem:

```
public struct MyStruct {
    internal int _someValue;
    public MyStruct(int someValue) {
        _someValue = someValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the `readonly` but it's still not working.  What other restrictions could be causing this?